# how to retrieve a string in xml parsing?

Tags: iphone

How to retrieve a string from a web service url using XML Parsing.

Comment: Make your question more specific

Comment: Give us an example about what you want.

Comment: for example if i want a string or word called apple from that web service url which is already stored tin that web service url. Like this i want many words to retrieve it from that url using xml parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/09/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/